# Making Single Camera follow multiple Objects in Unity

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am trying to build a 3D racing game with multiple vehicles but a single camera.

The idea is that players would try to knock each other off the track and one camera would capture all the action. I have tried a few things with the camera, for instance, the camera uses an average of all player transforms and follows it. However, this results in the camera movement being jumpy and discrete in certain places.

Does there exist a better approach instead of averaging all the transforms? The game requires the camera to follow players which are within 'D' distance of the leader.

Answer (score 1):

I understand from what I read that you're trying to create an 'Observer' camera (correct me if I'm wrong) which shows the overview of the game.

If so, the idea is change the camera mode from 'Follow' to 'Look At'. You can places multiple cameras around your track. When the group of the vehicles pass near any camera, you can switch the main camera to the closest to the group. Then you can make that camera 'Look At' the center of the group. Or if you really need to have one camera, you can just store positions around the track and move that camera to the position that is nearest to the group.

Further improvement is to make the camera 'Smooth Follow' (or smooth look at if you do my practice). You can do this by making the camera not immediately follow (look at) the target, but to lerp from current position and rotation to the required position, rotation.

Hope this help

kanpot2002